# I have installed virtualenv 1.9 which includes pip, but cannot install nltk

Tags: installation, nltk

I have installed virtualenv 1.9 which includes pip, but cannot install nltk on my Mac. First it does not recognize pip as a command. Second how do I install nltk?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run the following command to setup the virtual environment:

```
$ virtualenv venv
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools.............done.
Installing pip...............done.
```

Then activate the virtual environment using:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

Then install nltk:

```
(venv)$ pip install nltk
```

When you are done with the virtual environment run:

```
$ deactivate
```

You may want to try installing Python using Homebrew rather than using the Python version included with the OS.  With 'brew' you will not need to use virtualenv (unless you want to) because brew installs packages to /usr/local owned by you.  So you can simply run 'pip install '.

Follow the installation instructions [here](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/) for Homebrew.  Then run:

```
$ brew install python
$ pip install nltk
```

You can install virtualenv as well if you want it.

```
$ pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I have done and I just get no such file or directory.

Comment: I get Antoinettes-MacBook-Pro:virtualenv-1.9 antoinettearsic$ sudo pip install -U pyyaml nltk
sudo: pip: command not found

Comment: Do you get the same output from the virtualenv command that I get (above)?  Also, you should not need to use sudo, because the virtual environment is owned by you.

Comment: I can try Brew, thanks. I wondered about the sudo (and it asks me for a password), oddly the pip command never works. I do "ls pip" and get "no such file or directory" and the pip is in the right place. Also, when I "deactivate" in the virtualenv I also get "no such command."